# Laravel Relationship error trying to call a relationship within the model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

On Laravel "4.1.x-dev",

How can I call a method on a relation within the model?  From the below example

```
public function userLink() {
  return $this->user->link;
}
```

My function `userLink` gives me the error : `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Also is there another way for me to access the linked user from Drawing with some kind of eager loading trick?

[image]

I have several different type of **users**. Each type of user has it's own table with an **ID** in each table that corresponds to the *ID** of the **users** table. In my `Users` model I have a method called ''link'' that performs a ''morphTo'' and gets me the correct user object.

```
class Drawing extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }

    // this throws the relation error above, also I beleive this does two queries, anyway to improve this?
    public function userLink() {
        return $this->user->link;
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    public function link() {
        return $this->morphTo('User', 'type', 'id');
    }
}

class Retailer extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
    }
}

class Manufacturer extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call `userLink` method ?

Comment: $drawing = Drawing::first(); then $drawing->userLink

Comment: What happens if you call `dd(Drawing::first()->user)` ? What you get ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Drawing::first()->user->link;
```

or this:

```
// Drawing model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}

// Drawing model
// Requires above relation
public function userLink()
{
    return $this->user->link;
}
```

Then:

```
$ulink = Drawing::first()->userLink();
```

Also check the [Defining An Accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators).

**Update:** Just make changes to your method like this (Create an `accessor`):

```
public function getUserLinkAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->link;
}
```

Comment: WereWolf thank you this work but how can I make it so that I can call userLink without the parenthesis? for instance I can Call Drawing::first()->user I would like to be able to call Drawing::first()->userLink

Comment: Thanks WereWolf the problem is I still need to have the parenthesis in the call  How can I make it work with simply  Drawing::first()->userLink instead of Drawing::first()->userLink()

Comment: I tried but nothing gets returned when I do this, I'm also using the Laravel Console Plugin which shows SQL executed and the SQL is not executed with the scopeUserLink and $this->user->link and calling it with Drawing::first()->userLink

Comment: So when I edit scopeUser() and changed to dd($this->user->link) it does indeed give me back the right ->link object. However from outside the model, if I don't include the parenthesis then the relation doesn't get called. It still only works outside the model only if I add the parenthesis at the end of userLink Drawing::first()->userLink() = works Drawing::first()->userLink = doesn't work

Comment: I think I got it working! if I rename the function getUserLinkAttribute then I can now call ->userLink without the parenthesis!!!

Comment: Oops! yes thats it, I've posted the wrong thing, updating... :-)

Comment: Sorry for mis-confusion, Updated it :-)